# Default Pixel Format For FFMPEG For Encoding an Image Stack To Movie

Tags: ffmpeg

If one was converting a stack of images to a .mp4 with FFMPEG using libx264 to encode h.264 video and one didn't specify a pixel format in the call to FFMPEG is the default pixel format YUVJ420? I've been doing some experiments and have been getting results identical to if I specified YUVJ420 for my format versus if I specify no format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Output pixel format depends on the input pixel format, the encoder being used, and if you are performing any filtering.

According to `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264` this encoder supports the following pixel formats: yuv420p yuvj420p yuv422p yuvj422p yuv444p yuvj444p nv12 nv16 nv21.

By default `ffmpeg` will automatically perform pixel format conversion to one of the supported formats: whichever most resembles the source pixel format. You can increase the verbosity of the console output to see it in more detail using `-loglevel debug`. Example from a rgb24 input:

```
[format @ 0x55657882d6e0] compat: called with args=[yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21]
[format @ 0x55657882d6e0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21'
[format @ 0x55657882d6e0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x55657882eb00] picking yuv444p out of 8 ref:rgb24 alpha:0
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x55657882eb00] w:320 h:240 fmt:rgb24 sar:1/1 -> w:320 h:240 fmt:yuv444p sar:1/1 flags:0x4
```

Example to force a pixel format for the output: `-vf format=yuv420p` or `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This makes sense, the default had to do with the way my images were encoded to begin with.